# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Lesson.startdate received a naive datetime (2022-09-18 00:00:00) while time zone support is active. RuntimeWarning)

Tags: python, django, django-models

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Lesson.startdate received a naive datetime (2022-09-18 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
RuntimeWarning)

```
 def auto_send_notification(request):
   today = date.today()
   substatus = SubscribeEmailModel.objects.filter(topic__startdate=today, sent_mail=False)
```

Models.py

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
   startdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
   enddate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `datetime.date.today()`, use `django.utils.timezone.now().date()`.